# Questions dealing with nested quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I'm studying discrete mathematics now and I have trouble solving this question. The question is the next line.

> Let $Q(x,y)$ be the statement "student $x$ has been a contestant on quiz show $y$". Express each of these sentences in terms of $Q(x,y)$, quantifiers, and logical connectives, where the domain for $x$ consists of all students at your school and for $y$ consists of all quiz shows on television.

a) There is a student at your school who has been a contestant on a television quiz show.

b) No student at your school has ever been a contestant on a television quiz show.

c) There is a student at your school who has been a contestant on Jeopardy and on Wheel of Fortune.

d) Every television quiz show has had a student from your school as a contestant.

e) At least two students from your school have been contestants on Jeopardy.

and I thought

a) should be $\exists\, x \exists\, y(Q(x,y))$

b) should be $\lnot\exists\, x(\exists\, y(Q(x,y)))$

d) should be $\forall\, y(\exists\, x(Q(x,y)))$

and I don't know how to solve c), e).

I want to check my answers are right and solve c), e). I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers you have given are correct.

For the ones you can't solve, you need to realize that $Q(x,y)$ is a function, and you can substitute for the variables.  For example to express "John has been of a quiz show," we would say, $\exists y(Q(John,y))$

Now I'm sure you'll be able to do the other two.

BTW, please look at how I edited your question.  You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format questions on this site.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness! After reading your answer I concluded c) should be $\exists$ x (Q(x,Jeopardy) $\land$ Q(x,Wheel of Fortune)) and e) should be $\exists$ x (Q(x,Jeopardy) $\land$  $\exists$ y (Q(y,Jeopardy))). I don't know I'm right but your answer really helped me!

Comment: My pleasure.  Your answer to e) is not quite right.  You have overlooked the possibility that $x=y$.  You need $\exists x \exists y(x \ne y \wedge ... )$